# Delete all children when parent is deleted - frontend

Tags: front-end, customization

I have this function which I am using to enable front end page deleting which is working fine

```
function delete_post(){
global $post;
$deletepostlink= add_query_arg( 'frontend', 'true',   get_delete_post_link( get_the_ID() ) );
if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) {
    echo       '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return  confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="'.$deletepostlink.'">Delete this </a></span>';
}
}

//Redirect after delete post in frontend
add_action('trashed_post','trash_redirection_frontend');
function trash_redirection_frontend($post_id) {
if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'frontend', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {
    wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl').'/' );
    exit;
}
}
```

And then I use this is my template file for the button

```
<?php echo delete_post(); ?>
```

What I am looking to achieve is when a user deletes a page from the front end that it will also delete (or move to trash) all that parent pages children?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, interesting question. As far I've researched the hooks are called on deleting post passes the deleted post ID as parameter. At the time of deleting a parent page it works well but when you hooked a function on `trashed_post` to delete the child page it won't work cause every time it will get the trashed post id and here it'll be the ID of recently deleted child page. So it will not work as expected.

Now come to the solution. Here I've rewritten your functions with a SQL command to change the post status of the child pages to `trash`-

```
function delete_post(){
    global $post;
    $deletepostlink= add_query_arg( 'frontend', 'true',   get_delete_post_link( get_the_ID() ) );
    if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) {
        echo '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return  confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="' . $deletepostlink . '">Delete this </a></span>';
    }
}

//Redirect after delete post in frontend
add_action('trashed_post','trash_redirection_frontend');
function trash_redirection_frontend($post_id) {
    if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'frontend', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order'=> 'ASC',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_type' => 'page'
        );
        // Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
        $children = get_children( $args );
        global $wpdb;
        foreach($children as $child){
            $childs[$child->ID] = $child->ID;
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET post_status = 'trash' WHERE ID IN (" . implode( ', ', $childs ) . ")";
        $wpdb->query($sql);
        wp_redirect( get_option('siteurl').'/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Amazing!! Work's so well thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. Would you be able to assist with my other question - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252216/show-all-parent-pages-and-their-children-below-from-same-author-as-currently-vie